# What is readline in node JS?

Tags: node.js, readline

what is readline in NodeJS I don't known about it but I see many online test platform use readline please explain what is it

```
 readline
```

Answer (score 0):

> Readline allows reading of a stream (such as process.stdin) on a line-by-line basis.

for more information: [nodejs documentation on readline](https://nodejs.org/dist./v4.8.3/docs/api/readline.html)